# Can a HTTP error be cached?

Tags: http, http-status-code-403, twisted

We are using a Twisted HTTP server https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.0.0/web/howto/using-twistedweb.html
and we are experiencing a strange behavior.

This HTTP server serves a static file and in some cases it may returns a 403 to one person (tested in the office) while the rest of the team can download the file without any problem.

If the person receiving a 403 runs a curl the curl works fine, it looks like is something browser specific but my question is can a HTTP server error be cached for a specific request?

After a while the static file can be download fine by the user experiencing a 403.

Also how a 403 (forbidden error) can just affect to just a single request and not to everybody? **note there is not any kind of authentication.**

Edit: As far as I have tested, looks like the problem just appears in Google Chrome, with Firefox or curl it gets rendered fine although Chrome keeps giving me a 403. That browser is caching somehow the petition and if I try with incognito mode it works fine.

Comment: Normally you would record a reason as to why a request is denied in an (error) log. If no logging was enabled, now would be the right moment to do so, or maybe you need to increase the debug level

Comment: As far as I have tested, looks like the problem just appears in Google Chrome, with Firefox or curl it gets rendered fine although Chrome keeps giving me a 403. That browser is caching somehow the petition and if I try with incognito mode it works fine.

Comment: HTTP errors are not cacheable _by default_ but the web server can always send a Cache-Control header to override this. Of course, doing so is a terrible idea.